# table error: undefined control sequence

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make this table:

[image]

using this code:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
...
\begin{table}[]
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline
Tipo & Entidad & Variables & Expresión & ¿Cambia en el tiempo? \\ \hline
\multirow{37}{*}{Celda} & \multirow{37}{*}{Suelo} & \multirow{2}{*}{Estado del Suelo Atractivo} & Vivo & \multirow{2}{*}{Si} \\
 &  &  & Muerto &  \\
 &  & \multirow{8}{*}{Uso de suelo} & Vacante & Si \\
 &  &  & Habitacional & \multirow{7}{*}{No} \\
 &  &  & Turístico &  \\
 &  &  & Industrial &  \\
 &  &  & Agro-Industrial &  \\
 &  &  & Comercial &  \\
 &  &  & Equipamiento &  \\
 &  &  & Agrícola &  \\
 &  & \multirow{7}{*}{Interés} & Habitacional & \multirow{7}{*}{Si} \\
 &  &  & Turístico &  \\
 &  &  & Industrial &  \\
 &  &  & Agro-Industrial &  \\
 &  &  & Comercial &  \\
 &  &  & Equipamiento &  \\
 &  &  & Agrícola &  \\
 &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Urbano} & Si & \multirow{2}{*}{Si} \\
 &  &  & No &  \\
 &  & Renglón & Valor establecido por la matriz de compatibilidad & Si \\
 &  & Columna & Valor establecido por la matriz de compatibilidad & Si \\
 &  & Atracción & Valor numérico establecido por el modelo & Si \\
 &  & \multirow{2}{*}{¿Intersectado por vialidad regional?} & Si & \multirow{2}{*}{No} \\
 &  &  & No &  \\
 &  & \multirow{2}{*}{¿Apto?} & Si & \multirow{2}{*}{Si} \\
 &  &  & No &  \\
 &  & Subsector & Polígonos establecidos por el PDU & No \\
 &  & \multirow{2}{*}{¿Urbanizable?} & Si & Si \\
 &  &  & No & No \\
 &  & Potencial & Valor numérico establecido por submodelo & Si \\
 &  & \multirow{5}{*}{Pendiente} & 0-5% & \multirow{5}{*}{No} \\
 &  &  & 0-10% &  \\
 &  &  & 0-15% &  \\
 &  &  & 0-30% &  \\
 &  &  & >30% &  \\
 &  & \multirow{2}{*}{¿Cuerpo de agua?} & Si & \multirow{2}{*}{No} \\
 &  &  & No &  \\
\multirow{15}{*}{Ambiente} & Umbral de urbanización & Umbral de potencial & Valor numérico establecido por usuario & Si \\
 & \multirow{2}{*}{Preferencia por usos de suelo vecinos} & \multirow{2}{*}{Matriz de adyacencia} & Deseable & \multirow{2}{*}{No} \\
 &  &  & No deseable &  \\
 & Cumplimiento del Programa de Desarrollo Urbano & % industria compatible & Valor numérico establecido por usuario & No \\
 & \multirow{3}{*}{Población} & Tasa de crecimiento & Valor numérico establecido por usuario & No \\
 &  & Años de crecimiento & Valor numérico establecido por usuario & No \\
 &  & Número de habitantes & Valor numérico establecido por el modelo & Si \\
 & \multirow{8}{*}{Políticas públicas} & \multirow{2}{*}{Matriz de compatibilidad de usos de suelo} & Compatible & \multirow{2}{*}{No} \\
 &  &  & Incompatible &  \\
 &  & Densidad de población & Valor numérico establecido por usuario & \multirow{6}{*}{No} \\
 &  & \multirow{5}{*}{Restricción de pendiente} & 0-5% &  \\
 &  &  & 0-10% &  \\
 &  &  & 0-15% &  \\
 &  &  & 0-30% &  \\
 &  &  & >30% &  \\ \cline{4-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

but keep getting a series of undefined control sequence errors:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

character `%` has special meaning, all after it to the end of line is not considered in compilation but as comment. as you like to use it as "percent" symbol, you should write it as `\%`.

beside these errors your table has other issues too- it is to big that can be fit on page. also hasn't vertical and horizontal rules. for further help about this, please extend your code snippet to complete small document with your table that we can see which document class you use and layout of document page.

**edit:**
since you still not provide requested information below is an example of table without essential information about your document:

```
\begin{table}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\small
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} |l|
  >{\hsize=0.25\hsize\raggedright}X|
  >{\hsize=0.30\hsize\raggedright}X|
  >{\hsize=0.45\hsize\raggedright}X|
                                  c| 
                             @{}}
    \hline
Tipo & Entidad  & Variables     & Expresión & \makecell[b]{¿Cambia en\\ el tiempo?} \\ 
    \hline
\multirow{37}{*}{Celda} 
     & \multirow{37}{=}{Suelo} & \multirow{2}{=}{Estado del Suelo Atractivo} 
                                            & Vivo & \multirow{2}{*}{Si}            \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Muerto &  \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & \multirow{8}{=}{Uso de suelo} & Vacante & Si \\
    \cline{4-5}
 &  &  & Habitacional       & \multirow{7}{*}{No} \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Turístico          &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Industrial         &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Agro-Industrial    &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Comercial          &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Equipamiento       &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Agrícola           &  \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & \multirow{7}{=}{Interés} & Habitacional & \multirow{7}{*}{Si} \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Turístico          &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Industrial         &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Agro-Industrial    &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Comercial          &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Equipamiento       &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Agrícola           &  \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & \multirow{2}{=}{Urbano} & Si & \multirow{2}{*}{Si} \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & No                 &  \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & Renglón & Valor establecido por la matriz de compatibilidad & Si \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & Columna & Valor establecido por la matriz de compatibilidad & Si \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & Atracción & Valor numérico establecido por el modelo & Si \\
    \cline{3-5}
&  & \multirow{2}{=}{¿Intersectado por vialidad regional?} & Si & \multirow{2}{*}{No} \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & No &  \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & \multirow{2}{=}{¿Apto?} & Si & \multirow{2}{*}{Si} \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & No &  \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & Subsector & Polígonos establecidos por el PDU & No \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & \multirow{2}{=}{¿Urbanizable?} & Si & Si \\
    \cline{4-5}
 &  &  & No & No \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & Potencial & Valor numérico establecido por submodelo & Si \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & \multirow{5}{=}{Pendiente} & 0-5\% & \multirow{5}{*}{No} \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & 0-10\%     &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & 0-15\%     &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & 0-30\%     &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & >30\%      &  \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & \multirow{2}{=}{¿Cuerpo de agua?} & Si & \multirow{2}{*}{No} \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & No         &  \\
    \hline
\multirow{15}{*}{Ambiente} & Umbral de urbanización & Umbral de potencial & Valor numérico establecido por usuario & Si \\
    \cline{2-5}
 & \multirow{2}{=}{Preferencia por usos de suelo vecinos} 
    & \multirow{2}{=}{Matriz de adyacencia} 
        & Deseable & \multirow{2}{*}{No} \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & No deseable &  \\
    \cline{2-5}
 & Cumplimiento del Programa de Desarrollo Urbano & \% industria compatible & Valor numérico establecido por usuario & No \\
    \cline{2-5}
 & \multirow{3}{=}{Población} & Tasa de crecimiento & Valor numérico establecido por usuario & No \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & Años de crecimiento & Valor numérico establecido por usuario & No \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & Número de habitantes & Valor numérico establecido por el modelo & Si \\
    \cline{2-5}
 & \multirow{8}{=}{Políticas públicas} 
    & \multirow{2}{=}{Matriz de compatibilidad de usos de suelo}    
        & Compatible & \multirow{2}{*}{No} \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & Incompatible &  \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & Densidad de población & Valor numérico establecido por usuario & \multirow{6}{*}{No} \\
    \cline{3-5}
 &  & \multirow{5}{=}{Restricción de pendiente} & 0-5\% &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & 0-10\% &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & 0-15\% &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  & 0-30\% &  \\
    \cline{4-4}
 &  &  &  >30\% &  \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: please see edited answer. btw, why you first accept my answer and than change a mind?